# Javascript switch statement?

Tags: javascript

I have some code like below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Option.length; i++) {
    var option = $scope.Option[i].Code;

    if (option == "A") {
        $scope.aSelected = true;
        break;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Option.length; i++) {

    var option = $scope.Option[i].Code;

    if (option == "B") {
        $scope.bSelected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to right this in a switch statement like below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Option.length; i++) {

    var option = $scope.Option[i].Code;

    switch (option) {
        case "A":
            $scope.aSelected = true;
            break;
        case "B":
            $scope.bSelected = true;
            break;
        default:
            console.log('unrecognized option');
    }
}
```

Is this actually incorrect in the switch case because the first option may be A which will break out of the loop and then for example if 'B' was the option in a later position of the collection it would never get bSelected = true;

Comment: "Is this actually incorrect in the switch case" — Have you tested it? Does it have the behaviour you speculate it might have?

Comment: @Quentin - good point - should have just run a quick test - apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct because the BREAK inside of SWITCH will break out of it, not the whole FOR loop, and therefore it will check for B too.